# Remove multiple occurrences using SED command

Tags: linux, sed, perl

We had a requirement to remove all /t characters that are not followed by quotes

```
sed 's/\\t\([^"]\)/foo\1/g'
```

this command worked good for single occurrence. What option do we need to add remove multiple occurrences(consecutive occurrences)

Ex : `abc/t/tdef`

The above command is giving `abc /tdef` , but we are lokking for `abc def`

Comment: You are mixing `\t` and `/t`.  Which one is it? Is this the same question as [SED command to replace \t and not \t”(\t followed by quotes)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/726510) ?  If not, how do they differ?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$ cat file
abc/t/tdef
abc/t"/tdef

$ perl -pe 's|/t(?!")| |g' file
abc  def
abc/t" def
```

The part `(?!")` is a *negative look ahead* advanced regex technique, `sed` don't know about this

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's~(/t")?(/t)+~\1 ~' file
abc def
```

Comment: What about the requirements about double quotes ?